# Windows 10 activation is not working after latest update

Tags: windows, windows-10

On my 32bit computer I had installed Windows 10 Home and I activated by KMS and when my PC was updated and I got a message box every single day saying "Your Windows license expire soon" or something like that.

Now it's showing Your Windows is not activated and I can't activate again.

I tried to follow so many ways that did work for other people but in my case it's not working. I need it badly to active my Windows. Otherwise I can't fix my headphone issue also.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you the Administrator?  If you are not the Administrator then this cannot be solved by you.  Never heard of a headphone issue that requires Windows to be activated

Answer (score 2):

It quite clearly states that you need to be within your organisation for KMS to work.

KMS licences periodically renew themselves with the licence server within your company and fully expire after 180 days.

From [Microsoft Technet: KMS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793434.aspx)

> KMS activations are valid for 180 days—the activation validity interval. To remain activated, KMS client computers must renew their activation by connecting to the KMS host at least once every 180 days. By default, KMS client computers attempt to renew their activation every seven days.

If you have left the company and kept the computer, presumably with the companies permission, then you will need to buy a full licence for Windows yourself.

Otherwise simply take the computer back into work and let it activate itself over the network.

---

Unless you are talking about one of the KMS activation tools that you can download to activate Windows without paying for it... which means you *don't* have a valid copy of Windows at all.

KMS is a tool to allow companies to manage their Windows licences more effectively. With machines that may come into the office, get activated, get wiped and rebuilt it makes it easier to see how many licences they actually need and have them returned and reused easily.

KMS is **not** a free activation tool, though it may have been abused to allow temporary activations.

In that case you still don't have a valid licence for Windows because you didn't actually *buy* one. Or if you did buy it you did not get it from a reputable source and again still don't have a valid licence to use Windows.

If you truly "need" Windows then you need to buy a licence for it.